# Google webpage thumbnails absolute URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

**How can I get a list of either the absolute URI's or base64 encodings for page URL's in Google's search results?**

Goal:

Iterate through URL array:

```
pages["pinelakedesign.com"];
pages["pinelakedesign.com/about"];
pages["pinelakedesign.com/contact"];
```

Output:

- Google thumbnail 1
- Google thumbnail 2
- Google thumbnail N

Google is using base64 string encoding of thumbnail JPG images for their visual search results.  In 2011 this thumbnail service changed from the previous system with the magnifying glass and absolute URI construction described in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881319/google-web-thumbnails

I just want to tile out a list of the the pages in a website as Google thumbnails so I know which pages have been indexed and thumbnailed at a glance and what those thumbs all look like.

[image: Google search results thumbnail preview]

**Edit Nov 5, 2011**

I identified that a call to this URL returns JSONP with the base64 encoding, Google search result title, description and URL.

```
https://clients1.google.com/webpagethumbnail?r=4&f=3&s=400:585&query=pine+lake+design&hl=en&gl=us&c=29&d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinelakedesign.com%2F&b=1&j=google.nyc.c.j_pVK1Tu_gAbODsAKH0ZTuAw_3787232970_3&expi=17291,27615,28936,30049,30316,31215,32035,32271,32410,32940,33104,33194,33627,33788,33854,33907,33975,34103&a=2NT
```

The query= parameter is what was searched in Google. d= is the destination of the link, and possibly the source of the thumbnail.  s=400:585 is the height and width.  I am not sure what r=4 and f=3 do.  Modifying any of these variables results in a 404 error.  My hunch is that the expi= is some sort of checksum expiration algorithm based on the different parameter values but I don't know.

Returned JSONP:

```
google.nyc.c.j_pVK1Tu_gAbODsAKH0ZTuAw_3787232970_3({"s":"b","b":1,"quality":100,"shards":[{"heights":[300,131],"imgs":["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ ...THIS IS THE LONG BASE64 ENCONDING ...pa5r61f/9k="],"tbts":[{"box":{"h":15,"l":0,"t":39,"w":224},"txt":"<em>Pine Lake</em> specializes in small business website <em>design</em>, redesign and hosting. We have developed the Sungem content management system which allows our <b>...</b>","txtBox":{"h":57,"l":0,"t":58,"w":400}}]}],"url":"http://www.pinelakedesign.com/"}
)
```

---

**Update Nov 8, 2011**

I am looking for some solution like [emedly's Preview](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/preview?url=http://blog.embed.ly/31814817&maxwidth=500) for viewing Google thumbnails.

**Update Feb 9, 2012**

Using Phantom JS looks like a good way to achieve server-side remote snapshots but it does not help identify how to get at Google's images.

**Update Mar 26, 2012**

I believe Google's search spider is a headless version of desktop Chrome running 1024px wide resolution.  A Chrome spider would allow the spider to execute Javascript, use @font-face, CSS3 selectors, view Flash (even waiting for preloader to reaches 100%) and take accurate snapshots of the rendered pages after loading all assets and DOM manipulation.  Would anybody from Google please weigh in to confirm or deny anything?

Comment: Actually you can remove the expi parameter entirely. You can also remove the b and j parameters too. It looks like the a parameter is a checksum, as it's the only thing that seems to vary from one request to the next. Don't know a way to easily determine the value for a though.

Comment: just noticed that j is the JSONP callback wrapper.  @Todd, when I tried removing j,b or expi I got a 404 in Chrome.  Are you sending the request in the address bar or javascript?

Comment: In the address bar.. perhaps cookies also play a part?

Comment: Unfortunately nobody submitted an answer in time so Stack Overflow took the 50 point bounty (I don't get it back and nobody is allowed to win it).

Comment: Wish I could claim it, but I don't think I have enough to post to honestly take it. :(

Comment: @Dylan I suggest you add an answer you found and accept it - others searching for the solution on a similar problem may need the exact same thing.

Comment: @icyrock.com Unfortunately I don't have the answer yet or I would have posted it.  Generating screenshots with Phantom looks promising but I have not tested it thoroughly yet. Phantom is still a workaround from knowing the real URI of the Google thumbnails, which was the goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, they make an curl request for the query url first and then get the missing "a" parameter from the html response. Then they use it to construct the correct url and make the api call to google API to get the image. After that there is more complex work like merging resultant images with ImageMagick to get a full preview, but that's a plus...

Comment: you've got a good solution and it proves that its possible!  This doesn't exactly answer the question but since Thumbtool has a working prototype and he is adding an API I'm going to accept it.  If someone else posts a way to get directly Google's files with Javascript I'll be glad to change that to the correct answer.

Comment: I was equally impressed with Google's Russian translation as I was with the open sourced solution.  Thanks

Comment: I should add that this is no longer possible, as Google has disabled the instant preview feature.